# nested forms : update child foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a nested association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hostels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hostels
end

class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The form :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.label :email %><br>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<% f.object.hostels << @hostel -%>
<%= f.fields_for :hostels do |ff| %>
<%= ff.hidden_field :id %>
<% end -%>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end -%>
```

the controller

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  raise @user.hostels.inspect
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, hostels_attributes: [:id])
end
```

I would like to relink existing records of hostels to new users by updating hostel foreign key. This way, it definitly don't work.

Tried `update_only: true` parameter to nested too.

Any ideas about the subject or am I totally wrong about trying to do the operation like that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a multiple select for hotels in you form, then in the controller you must require hostel_ids.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hostels
end

class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Form: where :name is what you see in your multiple select

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :email %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :email %>
 <%= f.label "Hostels" %><br>
 <%= select_tag :hotel_ids, options_for_select(Hostel.all.map{|h| [h.name, h.id]}), { :multiple => true } %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, hostel_ids)
end
```

I did not test the code but must work well.

Comment: I think I should point out that most people will not want to put ALL models (in this case hostels) into their HTML. Mostly for performance and also for security reasons.